PowerApps, multi select checkboxes with input text box
I have sharepoint multi select field that I am using checkboxes in my PowerApps, if one of the checkboxes is checked, then I have a text input for the user to add some info.  How can I include that text input into my Update function on the DataCard?

Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to do? If one of the columns in SharePoint is a multi-select field (I'm assuming it's a choice field), where would the additional information entered by the user be stored? Multiple fields, single field? Without those details it's hard to understand your scenario.

It is a SharePoint multiselect choice field.  I have it set to allow Fill-Ins.  I was hoping I could have it show on the list something like this (these are the boxes checked):
CPFF, CPFF-C, CPFF-T, Hybrid
and when Hybrid is checked it would have the text box entry as (some text) so it would look like this:
CPFF, CPFF-C, CPFF-T, Hybrid - some text
But I do see what you mean about storing that information because I was able to get the Hybrid - some text to show in the SharePoint list, but then it didn't show the box checked or the fill in text when the form was opened back up.
